# Redirect user to original url from age verification

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url, redirect

I have the following function which redirects people to an age verification page if their session has expired:

```
function age_verification() {
   global $wp_session;

   if (is_admin()) 
       return false;

   $isAgeVerification = is_page('age-verification');
   $isAgeVerification = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'age-verification') !== false;

   if(!$isAgeVerification && $wp_session['age_allow'] == 0)
   {
       wp_safe_redirect( '/age-verification/' );
       exit;
   }

   if($isAgeVerification && $wp_session['age_allow'] == 1)
   {
       wp_safe_redirect( '/' );
       exit;
   }
}
add_action( 'init', 'age_verification' );
```

How do I get them to be redirected back to the the page they typed into the address bar originally? I've tried to capture `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but it gives me the current `/age-verification` page and not the page they were referred from. I also tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it is not set...

Is this possible with my current function? Thanks!

EDIT:

So whenever I call `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` I get the page that the browser is redirecting to (domain.com/age-verification). However, I've noticed that if I put an `exit;` immediately after my `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, I get the correct result. It's almost as if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is too slow and gets updated with domain.com/age-verification before it has a chance to get the current page before redirection...

Does that offer any more clues? What else can I provide to help out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the current REQUEST_URI to the Session before redirecting to age verification and use this value for redirecting back.
Another possibility is to put it in a URL Parameter when redirecting to age verification.

Comment: For some reason, I keep getting the age-verification page in my REQUEST_URI variable... I've even tried getting it before loading any of the functions but it always changes to /age-verification

Comment: This was the correct answer but I had to put it in an if statement to make sure it grabbed the original page and didn't change on redirection:

    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'age-verification') == false) {
            $wp_session['page'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }